# passing variable from factory to controller to view

Tags: angularjs

I cannot get the value I need in the controller from the factory.

This is my factory:

```
({
  countDoc: function(personId) {
    var deRelatedToPerson, deRelatedToPersonJSON;
    deRelatedToPerson = [
      {
        people: [personId],
        isActiveFilter: personId === 0 ? false : true,
        type: 'peopleAdvancedSearch',
        searchSection: 'peopleSearch'
      }
    ];
    deRelatedToPersonJSON = $filter("json")(deRelatedToPerson);

    return $http.post(advancedSearchDeBasePath + 'partialRecordCount/', deRelatedToPerson)
      .then(function(resp) {
        resp.data;
        return console.log(resp.data.data);
    });
  }
});
```

This is my controller:

```
bioPeopleFactory.countDoc(personId).then(function(resp) {
  $scope.totalDocNum = resp.data;
  return console.log(resp.data);
});
```

I get this console error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

seems that resp.data is undefined in the controller.

But the controller works and calls the fuction in the factory since the line 
return console.log(resp.data.data); in the factory gives me the right value I need in che console.log.

Yet i get:
[console.log](https://monosnap.com/file/a2TdBr4oL7PzbmZ21zdZKcIZPQ9Ni0)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the response to the success handler:

```
return $http.post(advancedSearchDeBasePath + 'partialRecordCount/', deRelatedToPerson)
  .then(function(resp) {
    resp.data;
    ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶s̶o̶l̶e̶.̶l̶o̶g̶(̶r̶e̶s̶p̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶)̶;̶
    console.log(resp.data.data);
    return resp.data;
});
```

This `.then` method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback or errorCallback.